# How to implement this function in a single line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

The resulting indices of the transformed light field data are ub, vb, sb, tb. Each of them is depending on variables u,v,s,t.

Sorry for being unclear, let me mention that I am trying to transform a 4D dataset through some sort of matrix. In the code below M is simply a 3D transformation matrix.

```
f=0.1; 
n = 11; 
[u,v,s,t] = ndgrid([1:Size(3)],[1:Size(4)],[1:Size(1)],[1:Size(2)]); 
alpha = M(3,1)*s+M(3,2)*t+M(3,3)*nf; 
beta1 = M(1,1)*u+M(1,2)*v+M(1,4); 
beta2 = M(2,1)*u+M(2,2)*v+M(2,4); 
C = M(3,1)*u+M(3,2)*v+M(3,4); 
D1 = M(1,1)*s+M(1,2)*t+M(1,3)*nf; 
D2 = M(2,1)*s+M(2,2)*t+M(2,3)*nf; 
ub = -D1.*C./alpha+beta1; 
vb = -D2.*C./alpha+beta2; 
sb = nf*D1./alpha; 
tb = nf*D2./alpha; 
for s = 1:Size(1) 
    for t = 1:Size(2) 
        for u = 1:Size(3) 
            for v = 1:Size(4)             
                newLF(sb(u,v,s,t),tb(u,v,s,t),ub(u,v,s,t),vb(u,v,s,t)) = LF2(s,t,u,v); 
            end;
        end; 
    end;
end;
```

Now since ub,vb,sb and tb are depending on u,v,s,t therefore, it is not possible to assign it like newLF = LF2;

Now the question is how to minimize these for loops to a single line.

Comment: it's a bit unclear, are you trying to [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)? `newLF=permute(LF2,[3 4 1 2]);`?

Comment: Explain with words what are you trying to achieve with your function and what are its inputs

Comment: Also, please supply a small set of sample values and expected outcome so that we know whether we are on the correct path. You are just wasting everyone's time otherwise.

Comment: This code should be in [How To Write Unmaintainable Code](https://thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)

Comment: @Shai, or on codegolf.SE ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

```
newLF = LF2;
```

Meaning, that code does nothing but copy `LF2` to `newLF`.

To check that I'm right, just let the code run with some random matrix `LF2` and then evaluate

```
all(newLF(:) == LF2(:))
```

and you'll find it always evaluates to "true".

---

First of all, your use of `sb`, `tb`, `ub`, `vb` is redundant. You are indexing into a grid, but this just reproduces the indices. The line

```
newLF(sb(u,v,s,t),tb(u,v,s,t),ub(u,v,s,t),vb(u,v,s,t)) = LF2(s,t,u,v);
```

is equivalent to the line

```
newLF(s,t,u,v) = LF2(s,t,u,v);
```

This of course is just element-wise copying.

The impression of permutation noted by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573198/how-to-implement-this-function-in-a-single-line-in-matlab#comment49216459_30573198) is given by the line

```
[ub,vb,sb,tb] = ndgrid([1:Size(3)],[1:Size(4)],[1:Size(1)],[1:Size(2)]);
```

which looks like you are preparing to permute dimensions (1, 2) with dimensions (3,4). However, you use this index grid in the form `sb, tb, ub, vb`, assigning the value from `s, t, u, v`, so the permutation is not actually performed.

---

Assuming you actually *do* want to do that permutation of dimensions, the correct code would be

```
for s = 1:Size(1)
    for t = 1:Size(2)
        for u = 1:Size(3)
            for v = 1:Size(4)
                newLF(u,v,s,t) = LF2(s,t,u,v);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

In this case Shai would be right, the corresponding one-liner is

```
newLF = permute(LF2, [3 4 1 2]);
```

Comment: I think you are on a winner... I ran it with random data and I got the same answer, i.e. `newLF == LF2`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, let me mention that I am trying to transform a 4D dataset through some sort of matrix.

Comment: f=0.1;
n = 11;
[u,v,s,t] = ndgrid([1:Size(3)],[1:Size(4)],[1:Size(1)],[1:Size(2)]);
alpha = M(3,1)*s+M(3,2)*t+M(3,3)*n*f;
beta1 = M(1,1)*u+M(1,2)*v+M(1,4);
beta2 = M(2,1)*u+M(2,2)*v+M(2,4);
C = M(3,1)*u+M(3,2)*v+M(3,4);
D1 = M(1,1)*s+M(1,2)*t+M(1,3)*n*f;
D2 = M(2,1)*s+M(2,2)*t+M(2,3)*n*f;
ub = -D1.*C./alpha+beta1;
vb = -D2.*C./alpha+beta2;
sb = n*f*D1./alpha;
tb = n*f*D2./alpha;
for s = 1:Size(1)  for t = 1:Size(2)  for u = 1:Size(3) for v = 1:Size(4)
newLF(sb(u,v,s,t),tb(u,v,s,t),ub(u,v,s,t),vb(u,v,s,t)) = LF2(s,t,u,v);
end;end; end;end;

Comment: Now since ub,vb,sb and tb are depending on u,v,s,t therfore, it is not possible to assign it like newLF = LF2;

Comment: And it is not an order issue of indices

Comment: By the way:
    M = gen3DTFMatrix(0,0,asind(tform.T(2,1)),tform.T(3,2),tform.T(3,1),0);

Comment: @UmairMukati there is no way we can read code posted in comments. please update your question to reflect content of your comments.

Comment: @UmairMukati, actually, you better ask a new question. I really wouldn't like my most elegant answer being invalidated by some update. ;-) Seriously though, your new code looks even more obfuscated than your old one. Indices being defined by floating-point operations?!